# Attempting to prove some inequalities

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am trying to prove that for large enoguh values of $x$ and for $\beta\in [\frac{1}{\log(x)},1]$, the following inequalities hold:

- $\frac{(1-\beta)x}{\log((1-\beta)x)}\geq \frac{x}{\log(x)}$
- $\frac{(1-\beta)x}{\log^2((1-\beta)x)}\geq \frac{x}{\log^2(x)}$

I'm not so sure how to go about it so I would appreciate any help I can get.
Thank you!